# Testing if a string has only one charater with or without a space in the middle REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I've this regex

```
`^([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{3})\s?((?!(.)\3{7}))([0-9]{4}\s?[0-9]{4}$)`
```

These are the scenarios : 
12 1234 1234 -> has to match 
12 1111 1111 -> cannot match 
12 12341234 -> has to match 
12 11111111 -> cannot to match

I cannot find a way to solve this

Comment: So you are testing the second part of the string checking if 2, 4 character words contain duplicate characters, and the word may or may not have a space between them?

Comment: That's it.
The problem is when i compare 1111+(space) with 1111 it doesnt trigger because of the space, and i dont know how to get away from it

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^[0-9]{2} ([0-9])(?!(?:\1| )+$)[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{4}$` https://regex101.com/r/2GocGD/1

Comment: That's it man!

Perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 2 sets of 4 digits should not exist of the same digits, you could use a negative lookahead using an alternation which will match either the backreference to group 1 or a whitespace char.

```
^[0-9]{2}\s([0-9])(?!(?:\1|\s)+$)[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{4}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9]{2}\s` Match 2 digits and whitespace char
- `([0-9])` Capture **group 1**, match the first digit of the first group of 4 digits
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `(?:\1|\s)+$` Match the same digits using a backreference to group or a whitespace char
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{4}` Match 3 digits, optional whitespace char and 4 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aT0unt/1)

---

Using the alternation at the start from your pattern to possibly also match 2 times 3 digits:

```
^(?:[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{3})\s([0-9])(?!(?:\1|\s)+$)[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{4}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SmMBBL/1)

Comment: What you typed in the comments was the perfect soluction, ill upvote anyway for the effort!